# I cannot find the graphical layout tab for xml on eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, user-interface, layout

I am trying to redesign the layout that we are using for our Android project but when I pull up the xml there is no graphical layout tab at the bottom. I am running eclipse helios on an XP. Does anybody know how I can Find it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Close the xml file
2. Right click on it in the navigator
3. Hover over open with
4. The editors associated with that file type will be displayed, and the default editor highlighted.

The default should be "XML Editor", if it is not, then by selecting it that should reset it to the default.
You can also check your default file associations under
 - Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations

If "XML Editor" is not available then ensure that you have the "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" installed.