# Android Eclipse does not show my Layout files in the Layout Editor be default

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have updated my Eclipse and some of my projects have stopped showing in the Layout Design(and instead shows a basic XML design),
What I have found, in order to open the Layout file I need  to right click and go to `Open with` and then selecting the `Show in Layout Editor`
I have a big Project I just can't keep on doing this, has anyone come across such problem? and a possible solution for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has already been addressed.Apparently, this problem happens in certain versions of ADT.Please check the marked answers from 
[No Graphical layout editor in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303103/no-graphical-layout-editor-in-android) and 
[I cannot find the graphical layout tab for xml on eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144685/i-cannot-find-the-graphical-layout-tab-for-xml-on-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I had tghis to but
after several times performing this action the layout editor was set to default